# CMS Open Payments API Response "Access Denied" for General Payments 2020

Tags: access-denied, json-api-response-converter

> CMS Open Payments API Response "Access Denied" for General Payments
> 2020

**General Payment Data - 2020**
The URL is: **https://openpaymentsdata.cms.gov/dataset/txng-a8vj**

How can I ***filter rows*** using this API? I've tried but it seems to not filter any rows and shows an error. It's not getting executed and shown me an error which says that “**access denied**”.

My tried query is below here:

**[SELECT * FROM 37ac320a-c4e2-50fd-b2e1-cfdeeaf93407][WHERE physician_profile_id = '8350']**

Please let me know if anyone from the StackOverflow community can help me to filter the rows.

Comment: Ran into the same problem... evidently using a WHERE clause causes this error. How did you proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem with using **GET /api​/1​/datastore​/sql** as soon as I add **[WHERE]** clause it returns **403 Access Denied**.

There is a way to filter your request by using this endpoint:

**POST ​/api​/1​/datastore​/query​/{distributionId}**

```json
{
  "conditions": [
    {
      "resource": "t",
      "property": "physician_profile_id",
      "value": 8350,
      "operator": "="
    }
  ],
  "limit": 10
}
```

Comment: Where would this code go?

Comment: If you asking about json, this is the body of the request. This may not be relevant anymore cause they were going through a lot of their APIs upgrades.